# Phonegap-Plugin ExternalFileUtil doesn't work on all devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using the ExternalFileUtil-Plugin from Phonegap (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ExternalFileUtil). But it work's only at iPhone. It work's on iPhone-simulator with iOS 6.0 and 6.1 and work's on iPhone 4 and 5 with iOS 6.x. But it doesn't work on iPad, neither on simulator nore on devices and on iPod Touch with iOS 5.1 it doesn't work too ;(

I've tried any suggestions described in the comments on http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/08/15/open-with-in-ios-phonegap-apps/ but nothing helps me.

In my opinion the following lines must be adjusted:

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *controller = [UIDocumentInteractionController  interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];
controller.delegate = self;
controller.UTI = uti;
[controller retain];

CDVViewController* cont = (CDVViewController*)[ super viewController ];
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, cont.view.bounds.size.width, cont.view.bounds.size.height);
[controller presentOptionsMenuFromRect:rect inView:cont.view animated:YES];
```

Have somebody any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution for this issue: Replace

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, cont.view.bounds.size.width, cont.view.bounds.size.height);
```

with this

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1500.0f, 50.0f);
```

and it works like a charm. Thanks to Mahendra Liya (see comment on [tricedesigns.com](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/08/15/open-with-in-ios-phonegap-apps/#comment-971407852)).